# Data Structures - choosing sorting method

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have 2 sorted arrays A[], B[]. My requirement is to merge this 2 sorted arrays and resultant array also should be in sorted manner. Since there is 2 sorted array I have 2 methods to solve this. One is using MERGE SORT method I can sort & another one I suggest is simply joining this 2 arrays and sorting the resultant array by quick sort method.

My question is in above two methods which one will have more efficiency , less run time , more stable. Please give me suggestion & also if there is any other solution is available please let me know.

Comment: I think quick sort should be faster than merge sort in terms of space and time complexity. 

But in-place mergesort is also possible. However, when mergesort is used with arrays, O(n) auxiliary space maybe required. Efficient implementations of quick sort use O(log n) space.

Comment: So best way is to merging those 2 arrays simply & finally sorting that resultant array using quick sort, correct me if am wrong..

Comment: @rabishaw uh... shouldn't merging two sorted arrays be *O(n+m)*? And likewise for space complexity (you have to allocate a new, full-sized array no matter what)? How would re-sorting the appended arrays possibly be faster than that?

Comment: @rabishaw note that the input arrays are already sorted.

Comment: Since the arrays are already sorted you can just use [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge).

Comment: @user657267 put that in an answer with an example so we can upvote.

Comment: What are *your* results of pondering on the above questions? How do you measure "efficiency" and "stable"? Which language are you using? What are the sizes of the two arrays? This smells like homework...

Answer (score 4):

With pre-sorted arrays, the simplest method should be something like

```
int A[50];
int B[50];
int C[100];

std::merge(std::begin(A), std::end(A), std::begin(B), std::end(B), std::begin(C));
```

Or if you're using `std::array`s

```
std::array<int, 50> A;
std::array<int, 50> B;
std::array<int, 100> C;

std::merge(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end(), C.begin());
```

Comment: This is not working , so could you please write down one clear example code to understand easily.

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxx If it's not working either your compiler does not support c++11 or you aren't passing the correct flag to enable support.

Comment: what you mean by flag ? should i do anything to make run this code or simply i can copy and paste this to execute ? could you please write the complete code ?

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxx What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Merging two **pre-sorted** arrays require only `O(N)` time and `O(N)` extra space where `N = n + m`. Here `n` and `m` are number of elements in each array.

In above case, if the two arrays are unsorted initially, you have to sort them in `O(nlogn)` and `O(mlogm)` time respectively. Then merging them require another `O(N)` time resulting in total `O(max(m, n) log max(m, n))` time asymptotically.

On the other side, if you join the two array and apply any first sorting algorithm like quicksort (C++'s `sort(..)`) the time complexity will be `O(NlogN)` and with `O(N)` extra space.

So it terms of time complexity, I think you should use merging method of merge sort as your two arrays are sorted initially.

Answer (score 0):

Not using classes, i.e. pure C:

```
void merge(int A[], int B[], int C[])
{
    int a, b, c;
    a= b= c= 0;

    while (a<50 && b<50) {
        if (A[a] < B[b])
             C[c++]= A[a++];
        else C[c++]= B[b++];
    }
    while (a<50) C[c++]= A[a++];
    while (b<50) C[c++]= B[b++];
}
```